# Python - How can I press a button(shift+F1) to activate a while True (key and mouseclick) and deactivate it on the same button?

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop, keyboard-events

I have this code in python (using vcode)

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import time

def mine():
    while True:
        try:
            if keyboard.is_pressed("shift+F1"):
                while True:
                    print("2")
                    pyautogui.click()
                    time.sleep(30)  
                    keyboard.press_and_release('1')
if __name__ == "__main__":
  mine()
```

And I want that the while True: to play and repeat itself when i press shift+F1 which currently works. Now the while True: is supposed to end itself when i press shift+F1 again and if I press it again the while True: should start again and so on. How do I do that, or what am I looking for? I am new to coding and python so I don't know alot

EDIT:

It now looks like this, but I still don't get what I am looking for... and I get stuck in the else: pass (when I place a print there is repeats the print infinitly and the shift+f1 doesn't work anymore)

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import time

def mine():
    while True:
        try:
            if keyboard.is_pressed("shift+F1"):
                while True:
                    if keyboard.is_pressed("shift+F1"):
                        print("ende")
                        break
                    else:
                        print("else")
                        pyautogui.click()
                        time.sleep(30)  
                        keyboard.press_and_release('1')
            else:
                pass   
        except:
            pass        
if __name__ == "__main__":
  mine()
```

Answer (score 0):

set a flag, as you press shift+F1 it will change flags condition. shift+F1 will be like a on/off button.
use time.sleep(0.5)(half second) to prevent multiple flag change for a one press shift+F1

```
import time
def mine():
    flag = True
    while True:
        if(flag):
            print("do something like pyautogui and pressandrelease 1")
        if(flag==True and keyboard.is_pressed("shift+F1")):
            flag = False
            time.sleep(0.5)
        elif(flag == False and keyboard.is_pressed("shift+F1")):
            flag = True
            time.sleep(0.5)
```